# MS Report builder expression if monday then today -3 days else - one dat

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I need to add a default date value to a parameter in report builder 3.0 
If today is monday then extract 3 day 
else extract 1 day. 
I have made an example in vb that works

```
If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = 1 Then

        TextBox2.Text = DateAdd("d", -3, Today())
Else
        TextBox2.Text = DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
End If
```

Now i want to do it in report builder, 
i tried following

```
=IFF (Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = 1,DateAdd("d", -3, Today()), IFF(Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) != 1,    DateAdd("d", -1, Today()))
```

I am not familiar with the syntax in report builder when using if then else. 
can someone give me an example.

Comment: Why not add an extra column (MondayAdd?) to the SQL query and use CASE to return the result. You could then use this value in the report rather than resorting to the IIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(WeekDay(Now(),VbMonday)=1,
DateAdd("d", -3, Today()),
DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
)
```

You are using an unnecessary nested IIF to evaluate the false part of the outer IIF.

Comment: Thank you, just what i needed.